# Centering 3 DIVs in CSS help?

Tags: html, css

http://www.magnixsolutions.com/dev/magicmorgan/indexnew.html

Im trying to have all three DIVs; left image, flash content in the middle, and right image to stay center. When I drag the size of the browser smaller, the div of the right image broke to the bottom. They should be fixed inline together horizontally with whatever size of the browser I minimize.

Also the flash in the middle is not aligned to the top? I cant understand what I did wrong.

Heres the code I did (I wasnt allow to display img tags on this website)

CSS:

```
    body{width:100%; margin: 0 auto 0 auto;}
    #content{text-align:center; }
    .content-left{width:362px; display: inline-block;}
    .content-center{width:950px; display: inline-block;}
    .content-right{width:427px; display: inline-block;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-left">LEFT IMAGE HERE</div>
    <div class="content-center">
     <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="950" height="1000" id="index" align="middle">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="movie" value="index.swf" />
            <param name="menu" value="false" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
            <embed src="index.swf" menu="false" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="950" height="1000" name="index" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">RIGHT IMAGE HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it does not render properly for screen below 1280x1024

Comment: I think you need the float directive in there AND you need to set the CONTAINING div to overflow: hidden  Unless the broswer is allowed to hide stuff as the browser size shrinks it will be wrapped.

Comment: The problem is that all your elements don't fit in a maximum of 1000px screen

Comment: Does that mean I need to reduce the two images smaller to fit the resolution size of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep them inline you need to express the widths in percentages so that they can get smaller as the screen gets smaller.  If the elements cannot be allowed to re-size than you need to give the body a fix width in pixels to maintain alignment.

Comment: I found the solution! Its white-space: nowrap; that did the trick and the right div didnt break when minimizing the browser smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Specify width for each of your three blocks

```
width:300px // this should be added for each of the three div
```

- note that the total width of the content must be equal or greater than 900px if all three are 300px wide. Otherwise the third div can not be accommodated in that 900px and will be shifted down to the next available place.